# Pasar registros de una tabla a otra de la misma BD en postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hola como puedo insertar datos de una tabla ya creada, a otra tabla con el mismo ID en postgresql.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Las columnas password y Email de tabla Personas recién fueron creadas para insertar los datos de la tabla PersonaLogin.** Ósea que password y Email de la tabla personas están vacíos.

En este ejemplo quiero pasar los datos de la tabla PersonaLogin a la tabla Perona las cuales comparten el mismo ID.

Investigando un poco probe con

```
update into personas set
????
```

Pero nunca funciono. esta ilustración y las tablas son de ejemplo para que sea más sencillo entender el problema.

Comment: ¿En postgresql 9.6 o 12? ¿Qué significa "nunca funcionó"? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y cuéntanos qué error te sale al usar esa consulta. Además, PersonaLogin tiene 3 campos y Persona tiene 2, por lo que usar `select *` va a traer 3 campos que no sabría nadie cómo insertar en dos (password, email).

Comment: Primero, si comparten el mismo ID quiere decir que los registros ya están en ambas tablas, por lo tanto no lo podrías insertar (porque el ID es la clave primaria), y te daría error por ID duplicado. Segundo cuando haces un `INSERT` a partir de un `SELECT`, tienen que coincidir la cantidad y tipo de datos de las columnas especificadas en ambos (y en el mismo orden). Quizas lo que estás buscando es actualizar los registro de una de las tablas a paritr de los datos que están en la otra tabla, ¿es correcto?.

Comment: Listo @Alfabravo.

Comment: Con respecto a lo de @nachospiu los registros no estan en ambas tablas yo recien le cree los 2 campos a la otra tabla

Comment: El error no tiene  nada relacionado con la consulta que muestras: `where alumnos.alum_idalumno = pf_alumnospassword.pfap_idalum...`. Yo sé que es aburrido pero imagínate cómo es de este lado no saber qué es lo que estás viendo e intentando. Adivinar no es divertido

Comment: PD. Seguimos sin saber cuál es la versión de pgsql y ni idea qué tiene que ver tsql (lenguaje usado en SQL server) en tu pregunta.

Comment: @matiassanchez creo que tienes un error de concepto. A partir de la edición de tu pregunta entiendo que lo que quieres es actualizar la información de la tabla `personas` (nombre y password) a partir de la información de la tabla `personaLogin` utilizando los IDs. Por lo tanto en lugar de un `INSERT` tienes que hacer un `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para actualizar la información de las columnas `Password` e `Email` de la tabla `Persona` a partir de la información de la tabla `PersonaLogin`, utilizando los `ID`s para vincular, la query sería la siguiente:

Me base en la estructura de las tablas que se ven en la imagen.

```
UPDATE Persona p
SET Password = pl.Password, 
    Email = pl.Email
FROM PersonaLogin pl
WHERE p.ID = pl.IDPersona;
```

Comment: Hola @nachospiu genial si si perfecto, me re sirvió muchas gracias, era un problema de concepto, muchas gracias..!

Comment: De nada @matiassanchez!!! Me alegro que mi query te haya sido util!

Comment: Si re util @nachospiu muchas gracias